# MySQL Python query works alone but fails when parameterized

Tags: python, mysql, json

Basically, I have a MySQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE markets (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    root_symbol VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    metadata JSON NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The metadata column contains a JSON document like this:

```
metadata = {
    'tick_size': 0.01, 
    'currency': 'USD'
}
```

In Python, the following 2 lines work:

```
cur.execute("SELECT root_symbol FROM markets WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, '$.currency') = 'USD'")
cur.execute("SELECT root_symbol FROM markets WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, '$.tick_size') = 0.25")
```

Yet when parameterized, these 2 don't:

```
cur.execute("SELECT root_symbol FROM markets WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, '$.%s') = %s", ('currency', "USD"))
cur.execute("SELECT root_symbol FROM markets WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, '$.%s') = %s", ('tick_size', 0.25))
```

Can somebody explain to me why and how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parameterize the whole field value for the `JSON_EXTRACT()`:

```
cur.execute("""
   SELECT root_symbol 
   FROM markets 
   WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, %s) = %s""", ('$.currency', "USD"))

cur.execute("""
   SELECT root_symbol 
   FROM markets 
   WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, %s) = %s""", ('$.tick_size', 0.25))
```

Note the absence of quotes around the placeholders - the database driver would put it automatically if needed.